# Como importar pydensecrf.densecrf?

Tags: python, import

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro quando tento executar o código:

```
ImportError: No module named densecrf
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu estou usando Jupyter Notebook 5.5.0 from Anaconda no Ubuntu 18.04

Alguém sabe o que poderia ser? Eu tento inserir a pasta **pydensecrf** na pasta do meu projeto, mas ainda recebo o mesmo erro.

Eu instalei o **pydensecrf** usando o comando:

```
pip install pydensecrf
```

Eu também tentei instalar com:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pydensecrf
```

mas recebo o mesmo erro para ambos.

Comment: Como o Jupyter foi instalado?

Comment: I installed anaconda and it installed Jupyter itself.

Comment: Oi, eu não consegui replicar teu erro, criei no Ubuntu 18.04 um ambiente para o Python 3 usando o Virtualenv, entrei nele, instalei o Jupyter e o pydensecrf via PIP e tudo funcionou normalmente (claro, não usei o Anaconda, fiz diretamente com os recursos da distribuição).

Comment: Oi Giovanni, eu consegui resolver o erro. Eu estava criando meu projeto Notebook dentro da pasta workspace/models/research/slim dessa biblioteca que eu baixei: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim

Porque eu precisava de usar a VGG 16. Depois que criei o projeto notebook na minha home, o pydensecrf funcionou normalmente. Obrigada pela atenção!